# Not able to loop table rows in the table?

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table

```
let tableclientnamelist  = [];
        for(var i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
            tableclientnamelist.push(
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {tableclientname[i]}
                   </td>
               </tr>
            )
         }

    let tablecreatedbylist  = [];
        for(var i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
            tablecreatedbylist.push(
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {tablecreatedby[i]}
                   </td>
               </tr>
            )
         }

         let tablecontractvaluelist  = [];
        for(var i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
            tablecontractvaluelist.push(
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {tablecontractvalue[i]}
                   </td>
               </tr>
            )
         }

         let tablecreatedDatelist  = [];
        for(var i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
            tablecreatedDatelist.push(
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {tablecreatedDate[i]}
                   </td>
               </tr>
            )
         }  


          <table id="customers">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Client Name</td>
                                                 <td>Created By</td>
                                                  <td>Contract Value</td>
                                                   <td>Created Date</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {tableclientnamelist}
                                            {tablecreatedbylist}
                                            {tablecontractvaluelist}
                                            {tablecreatedDatelist}




                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCD4V.png)

I have a table and i need table rows based on the array names.
showing error, May I know whats wrong in this or any other way need to implement

I have updated the changes after inseting all are coming in a sigle column
instead of coming in 4 different columns as i have 4 different tds

Comment: Can you show any error message. or may your list is empty. I think `<td>` should inside for loop.

Comment: I have tablecontractlist of length 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` instead.

change tabe datat from

```
<td>{for(var i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
                tableclientname[i]
            }}</td>
```

to

```
{
  tablecontractlist.map((table, i) => {
    return (                
       <tr key={i}>
         <td>{tableclientname[i]}</td>
         <td>{tablecreatedby[i]}</td>
         <td>{tablecontractvalue[i]}</td>
         <td>{tablecreatedDate[i]}</td>
      </tr>
    )    
 })
}
```

Comment: same here also i am getting all the values in a single column instaed of coming in 4 columns as i have 4 tds

Comment: @sivasai081 thats because you are doing it wrong. Understand your data use do it the right way. See my update above. It should work

Answer (score 0):

In your `render()`:

```
let list  = [];
for(let i=0; i<tablecontractlist.length;i++){
    list.push(
       <tr key={i}>
           <td>
              { tableclientname[i] }
           </td>
       </tr>
    )
 }
```

Then, in your `return` at `tbody`:

```
 <tbody>
      { list }
 </tbody>
```

Comment: I have updated the latest code can you check has i am getting all tds in a signle column i have 4 tds it should be displayed in 4 columns as per header

Comment: So, it work, and now you have new problem ? Please take a screen shot your tabe trouble...

Comment: i have attached in question

Comment: where i am getting all columns result in single column
instead of 4 different columns

Comment: Loop once and push more `<td></td>` instead create 4 array

Answer (score 0):

[image]    In tbody you are just displaying the values without corresponding **tds** to it... Just for you info... I have added the same list for contract value and created date, if in case you wondering why its displaying the same values.

```
Sample code:

 state = {
 clientList: [{name: 'abc'}, {name: 'def'}],
 createdDateList: [{name: '01/02/2001'}, {name: '01/02/2010'}]

}

render methods for list:

const renderClientList = clientList.map((value, key) => {
            return <tr>
            <td>
               {value.name}
            </td>
        </tr>
        });

        const renderCreatedDateList = createdDateList.map((value, key) => {
            return <tr>
            <td>
               {value.name}
            </td>
        </tr>
        });


<table id="customers">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Client Name</td>
                                                 <td>Created By</td>
                                                  <td>Contract Value</td>
                                                   <td>Created Date</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <td>{renderClientList}</td>
                                            <td>{renderCreatedDateList}</td>
                                            <td>{renderClientList}</td>
                                            <td>{renderClientList}</td>




                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Hope this helps :).. please check how renderClientList is placed and also I have used map :D